# Excel formula for VLOOKUP with changing look-up value across all rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table in Sheet1, which will be a password-protected worksheet:

```
A1: ZIP Code B1: City Name
A2: 8272     B2: Manila
A3: 6225     B3: Quezon City
A4: 2986     B4: Caloocan
A5: 1632     B5: Zamboanga
```

In Sheet2, I have the following column headers:

```
A1: Select ZIP Code B1: City Name
```

Basically, in Sheet2, cells under column A are drop-down lists containing the ZIP codes in Sheet1. Once a user selects a ZIP, the corresponding city name should appear to the right, just so the user can visually confirm that he/she entered the correct ZIP code.

I've managed to retrieve all the ZIP numbers from Sheet1 and put them in drop-down lists to all cells from Sheet2!A2 downwards. My problem is: In Sheet2, how do I display the corresponding city name in B[rownum] based on what is selected in A[rownum]? I tried using VLOOKUP but can't seem to dynamically point to the look-up value (the first argument in VLOOKUP) across all the rows beneath Sheet2!B1. I need a formula, not VB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got this.... Sheet1 is the database.
Sheet2 you will enter zip codes in column A and you want the city names to appear formulaically in column B.

In B2, put this formula and copy down:

```
    =IF($A2="", "", VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A:$B, 2, 0))
```